# Which is the difference between the two Greek BERT models?

Tags: nlp, pytorch, bert

I want to use the Greek BERT which can be found here https://huggingface.co/nlpaueb/bert-base-greek-uncased-v1

However I am confused about which model should I use and which are the differences.

The tokenizer is the same

```
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained('nlpaueb/bert-base-greek-uncased-v1')
```

but we have two models

```
model = AutoModel.from_pretrained("nlpaueb/bert-base-greek-uncased-v1")
model = AutoModelWithLMHead.from_pretrained("nlpaueb/bert-base-greek-uncased-v1")
```

Which one should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main difference between the two models is that the first one is a general BERT model without a specific head that simply returns the raw hidden states of the model, whereas the second one has an architecture with a language modelling head on top. You can find some more info in the `huggingface` documentation, compare for example the explanation of the [`BertModel`](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/model_doc/bert#transformers.BertModel) versus the [`BertLMHeadModel`](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/model_doc/bert#transformers.BertLMHeadModel).

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. So If I want to finetune the bert model for a classification task which model should I use? From your answer I think these are the same models where if I use the first one (AutoModel.from_pretrained) I must construct the classification layer, while if I use the second one (AutoModelWithLMHead) there is a function for the classification task. Is that right?

Comment: The first model simply returns the last hidden state from the model, the second one returns the scores for each token in the vocabulary.